# How to Create a Simple To Do Script on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-8, batch-file

I built simple todo script that adds a text file to desktop for every todo item. **I need help to simplify the process of launching this script:**

Step 1) Create todo.bat file on Desktop, with the following command

> echo.>%1.txt

Step 2) Right-click on Desktop > Open Command Window here

Step 3) Type:

> todo remember-the-milk

Step 4) Exit Command Line

Step 5) Notice that Desktop now contains

> remember-the-milk.txt

I am running Windows 8.1, and I used a batch file to make this script work, but I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Zach Holman from GitHub was able to accomplish this script using UNIX. See: http://zachholman.com/posts/inbox-zero-everything-zero/

Comment: You could create a bat file and make a shortcut on your toolbar.  Then whenever you click on this it would simply bring up your executing bat script that is asking you for the todo name and saves a file to the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're doing is creating text files whose names are your "to-do" items, you really don't need a batch file. Just right-click the desktop, select **New -> Text Document**, and type your text.

But it's beyond me why you'd want to do it this way rather than use any of a bazillion programs out there that implement task lists, or simply create one text file with all your tasks listed in it, and keep that file in an open notepad window (be sure to get into the habit of hitting **Ctrl-S** *every* time you add an item, to save yourself a lot of frustration).

Comment: I am using Zach Holman's approach to emptying things. He says "I keep a clean desktop: under three icons at a time, preferably. It made sense to use my desktop as a kind of bucket I needed to empty: it's always there, and I can put short, actionable items there because that visually disturbs me enough to want to clean it off (and do the action)."

Comment: Whatever works for you. Anyway, this is the simplest way to do it. You don't need a batch file. You don't even need to have the .txt extension, though if you select "Text Document", you'll have to delete the extension and dismiss a pop-up warning about changing the extension each time, so you'll find it less of a hassle to create folders instead (the same way--select **Folder** from the **New >** submenu of the desktop's context menu).

Comment: Thanks Adi. Creating either a Text Document or a Folder is the simpler solution to this "purge your desktop" method.

Answer (score 0):

This will work as `todo.bat` on your desktop which can be clicked on:
Just be aware that some illegal filename characters like `>` `<` `|` `?` `*` will cause it to fail.

```
@echo off
set "text="
set /p "text=Type in your todo reminder: "
if defined text type nul>"%text%.txt"
```

The `type nul` creates a zero byte file which takes no room on the hard drive, as the name is only stored in the existing file tables.